# 'too many values to unpack', iterating over a dict. key=>string, value=>list

Tags: python

I am getting the `too many values to unpack` error. Any idea how I can fix this?

```
first_names = ['foo', 'bar']
last_names = ['gravy', 'snowman']

fields = {
    'first_names': first_names,
    'last_name': last_names,
}        

for field, possible_values in fields:  # error happens on this line
```

Answer (score 592, accepted):

### Python 3

Use [`items()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

```py
for field, possible_values in fields.items():
    print(field, possible_values)
```

### Python 2

Use [`iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems).

```py
for field, possible_values in fields.iteritems():
    print field, possible_values
```

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294899/1489538) for more information on iterating through dictionaries, such as using `items()`, across Python versions.

For reference, [`iteritems()` was removed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists).

Comment: As for why you need to do this, iterating over a dictionary iterates through the keys, not the key/value pairs.

Comment: @jeffm that's what confused me. i saw this as a PHP foreach.

Answer (score 89):

For Python 3.x `iteritems` has been removed. Use [items](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) instead.

```
for field, possible_values in fields.items():
    print(field, possible_values)
```

Answer (score 40):

You want to use [iteritems](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems). This returns an iterator over the dictionary, which gives you a tuple(key, value)

```
>>> for field, values in fields.iteritems():
...     print field, values
... 
first_names ['foo', 'bar']
last_name ['gravy', 'snowman']
```

Your problem was that you were looping over fields, which returns the keys of the dictionary.

```
>>> for field in fields:
...     print field
... 
first_names
last_name
```

Answer (score 14):

For lists, use `enumerate`

```
for field, possible_values in enumerate(fields):
    print(field, possible_values)
```

`iteritems` will not work for list objects

Comment: This should be a correct answer (tested) for python 2.7 at least.

Comment: The question is about a dictionary, not a list. Either way, those names are wrong: "`field`" is actually an index, and "`possible_values`" is actually the field.

Answer (score 4):

you are missing `fields.iteritems()` in your code.

You could also do it other way, where you get values using keys in the dictionary.

```
for key in fields:
    value = fields[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 `iteritems()` is no longer supported

Use `.items`

```
for field, possible_values in fields.items():
    print(field, possible_values)
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466625/4518341) and others already cover `dict.items()` in Python 3.

Comment: @wjandrea top answer was added later by updating old answer. In 2018 mine was the only answer.

Comment: OK, you're right that the top answer was updated, but [Meistro's answer](/a/28842588/4518341) was not.

Answer (score -1):

Can't be iterating directly in dictionary. So you can through **converting into tuple**.

```
first_names = ['foo', 'bar']
last_names = ['gravy', 'snowman']

fields = {
    'first_names': first_names,
    'last_name': last_names,
         } 
tup_field=tuple(fields.items())
for names in fields.items():
     field,possible_values = names
     tup_possible_values=tuple(possible_values)
     for pvalue in tup_possible_values:
           print (field + "is" + pvalue)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just thought I'd throw this in. I have the "too many values to unpack (expected 2)" crop up today. Infuriating but is was due to missing a comma in a choice list.

```
CapTextureChoices = [
("initial", ""),
("Shaggy", "Shaggy"),
("Wrinkled", "Wrinkled"),
("Striate," "Striate"),
("Downy", "Downy")
]
```

the missing comma between "Striate," "Striate" was the culprit

Comment: This is the answer to a different question. Normally I'd say post it separately, but where the cause was a typo, I wouldn't bother. Please read [ask].