# Filtering dictionary keys by a function of their associated values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count, nested

I have a dictionary like this

```
my_d = {"a": [1, 2, 2, 5, 2],"b": [2, 1, 2, 4, 5],"c": [7, 2, 2, 6, 2],"d": [7, 2, 2, 2, 1]}
```

I am looking for the keys whose dictionary values contain "2 and less than 2" more than twice. In the example, that would be "a","b", "c","d". the following code only find those whose dictionary values contain 2 more than twice:

```
for key, item in my_d.items():
    if item.count(2) > 2:
        print key,
```

Comment: I don't think this has a great deal to do with the fact that the lists are in a dict, and is more just a question about some particular counting of items in a list.  In other words, the part where dict keys are returned for associated values that meet some criterion is trivial.

Comment: The description is a little ambiguous. Would you want `[ 1, 2, 3, 4]` to match the criteria? It has two numbers <= 2, but neither of them occur >= 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the items and check if the first two elements are ≤2:

```
>>> for key, item in my_d.items():
...   i=sorted(item)
...   if all(map(lambda x:x<=2,i[:2])):
...     print key,
...
a c b d
```

or, since you only have 2 elements to check:

```
>>> for key, item in my_d.items():
...   i=sorted(item)
...   if i[0]<=i[1]<=2:
...     print key,
...
a c b d
```

Comment: Note: this answer has the worst time and memory complexity

Answer (score 1):

```
[key for key, item in my_d.items() if len([i for i in item if i<3]) > 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, it's a simple [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

```
for key, item in my_d.items():
    if len ([x for x in item if x <= 2]) > 2:
        print key
```

What it does is building a list of all elements in `item` that are less or equal to 2, and checks the length of the generated list.

Comment: Dunno, the code works perfectly for the dictionary in the question. but I have a dataset with around 32000 rows and 52 columns. I already exported that into a dictionary. when I test out your code for such a big dictionary, it gave this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack.

Comment: @ali that error may be caused by something else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466618/too-many-values-to-unpack-iterating-over-a-dict-key-string-value-list

Comment: Dunno. I think I just discovered the problem. when I make the dictionary the values would be string not integer like this:      my_d = {"a": ['1', '2', '2', '5', '2'],"b": ['2', '1', '2', '4', '5'],"c": ['7', '2', '2', '6', '2'],"d": ['7', '2', '2', '2', '1'],"e":['1','3','4','2','6']}. I used int() function but did not work

Comment: Comparing a string to integer doesn't cause `ValueError`

Answer (score 0):

```
print [k for k, v in my_d.items() if len(filter(lambda x: x <= 2, v)) > 2] # ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this -

```
f1 = lambda x: [obj for obj in x if obj <= 2]

results = [k for k, v in d1.items() if len(f1(v)) >= 2]
```

Which runs the lambda function on every value

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> my_d = {"a": [1, 2, 2, 5, 2],"b": [2, 1, 2, 4, 5],"c": [7, 2, 2, 6, 2],"d": [7, 2, 2, 2, 1],"e":[1,3,4,2,6]}
>>> [k for k,v in my_d.items() if len([i for i in v if i<3])>2]
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```