# How to extract all but the list in a dict

Tags: python

I can't seem to be able to figure out how to extra all but the list inside this json object. The error I keep getting is `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

```
data = { k:v for (k, v) in organization_types_json if k != organization_types_json['organization_type_names']}
```

Json:

```
{
    "is_active": 0,
    "is_delete": 1,
    "organization_type_names": [{
        "lang": "EN",
        "name": "Fire"
    }, {
        "lang": "FR",
        "name": "Feu"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466618/too-many-values-to-unpack-iterating-over-a-dict-key-string-value-list

Comment: I think the error is saying `{ "lang": "FR", "name": "Feu" }` doesn't have a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.items()` like so:

```
data = { k:v for (k, v) in organization_types_json.items() if k != 'organization_type_names'}
```

Or extract all and remove that item.

```
d = dict(organization_types_json)
del d['organization_type_names']
```

Comment: which method do you recommend? My use case is I am receiving a json string that contains data for 3 tables. The nested part represent a child table.

Comment: @Joshua Well, either method will work. I believe deleting it afterwards is nicer and more efficient computation-wise. The other method is more efficient memory wise but doesn't look as good I believe.