# how to insert bulk data in django

Tags: python, django

After form submit I am getting data like this. Now I want to insert this data by the loop in a model or in the table using a for loop.

```
{'user_id': ['4'], 
'type': ['1'],
 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['Umvdq9BhNUNg94XZNDwkzXfhbjwZY91vKfyqsgBsGAXeRG9NS2DAB87Jvgv3NQlx'], 
 'vehicle_no[]': ['ertere', '11', '2222'], 
 'mileage[]': ['eere', '111', '2222'], 
 'vehicle_category[]': ['1', '1', '1'],
  'status[]': ['2', '2', '2']
}
```

After this, I am doing this to get the data:

```
for k,v in vals:
   print(vals)
```

to get values so I can insert it into DB with `multiplke` rows, but when I am doing the same I am getting the following error:

> too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I am stuck here. If anyone has an idea please share or solve my issue.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466618/too-many-values-to-unpack-iterating-over-a-dict-key-string-value-list

Comment: print(vals)  - here  you are taking entire object instead of keys and values -

Answer (score 1):

What you are printing is the whole dictionary in place of key and value pair.
try using:

```
for k,v in vals.items():
   print([k,v])
```

Also, Since you are not changing data from the form, to make things easier, you might consider using the Django forms, it will make things a lot easier for you.