# Unpacking iterables in Python3?

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Why is this returning `in sort_tup_from_list for key, val in tup: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

```
# list with tuples
lst = [("1", "2"), ("3", "4")]

# sorting list by tuple val key
def sort_tup_from_list(input_list):
    tmp = []
    print(tup)
    for tup in input_list:
        for key, val in tup:
            tmp.append((val, key))
            tmp.sort(reverse=True)
    return tmp

print(sort_tup_from_list(lst))
```

When I comment out second `for` loop, it prints tuple:

```
lst = [("1", "2"), ("3", "4")]
def sort_tup_from_list(input_list):
    tmp = []
    for tup in input_list:
        print(tup)
        # for key, val in tup:
        #     tmp.append((val, key))
        #     tmp.sort(reverse=True)
    return tmp

print(sort_tup_from_list(lst))
```

Output:

```
('1', '2')
('3', '4')
[]
```

So, tuples are there. Why are they not unpacking themselfs?

Comment: Because you iterate over `tup`. And the elements of `tup` are single character strings. If you had entered two-char strings, they would unpack in two variables with chars.

Comment: You are right! Adding two-char strings works as expected but this was not what I wanted. Problem solved ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second for loop is looping through items in the tuple, but you're grabbing both of the items in it. I think this is what you want:

```
# list with tuples
lst = [("1", "2"), ("3", "4")]

# sorting list by tuple val key
def sort_tup_from_list(input_list):
    tmp = []
    print(tmp)
    for key,val in input_list:
        tmp.append((val, key))
        tmp.sort(reverse=True)
    return tmp

print(sort_tup_from_list(lst))
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I see now when looping through tuple I can have only one iterable